# How do I make a MIDI file to reset the Reverb and Chorus on my Roland synthesizer?

Tags: midi, synthesizer

When playing different MIDI files on my Roland SC-55 I found that not all of them explicitly set their own Reverb and Chorus. This results in the playback of subsequent files having otherwise random settings applied to them as a result of inheriting whatever values existed from the previous one.

To compensate for this, I have to manually reset the synthesizer from the display panel buttons between each file.

The defaults for this device are: Level: 100 / Pan: 0 / Reverb: 40 / Chorus: 0.

How can I construct a MIDI file that I can play between tracks which will reset my synthesizer to these default values so that music will play back as expected?

Comment: Pages 72-85 in the user manual cover this. 

There's a whole section about constructing SysEx messages and they've even made it easy by using standard CC implementation (07=Level, 91=Reverb, 93=Chorus). Use your DAW or midi tool to set those CC channels to the values you want. You could even set up a controller so that you can adjust these values on the fly.

There are a number of groups on Facebook and other social media that specialise in the workings of particular synths, I suggest you find and join one that is relevant. They will help you get more specific support.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* reset specific controllers by sending your chosen values -
CC07 Volume 100
CC10 Pan 64 [zero is hard left, centre is 64]
CC91 Reverb 40
CC93 Chorus 0

There is a Reset All controller 121, however it specifically avoids resetting FX params, so won't be useful to you in this case.

The accepted method to reset everything before playback of a new GM song is to send
SysEx `F0 7E 7F 09 01 F7`
which is the universal GM System On message, right at the head of your track. This will default the entire machine & prepare it for GM playback, so each song will contain only the changes applied by the programmer for that specific song, no left-overs at all from the last song. Allow 200ms for it to react before sending your song setup. If you do this in a dedicated setup bar, you will have plenty of time for even something as old as the SC55 to respond in time.

Comment: Is there a free tool I can use to convert these hex values to a MIDI file? Ideally, I would like to inspect other "reset" .mid files I've found that did not work as expected for comparison.

Comment: You just need any DAW with a "list" edit mode. You should be able to just click new event data in, usually with a pencil tool or such. There should be a menu in the editor to add Note, CC, SysEx etc, which you can then just type into the list once the blank event is entered. Any GM file with a proper [or even improper] setup bar will be throwing out all the necessary data to set up the song in that first bar. At the head of it should be the SysEx reset. [I'm aware from vast personal experience that many *many* ***many*** amateur Midi song file makers don't really know how to do this properly;)